# React Select giving formik.touch issues

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-select

Hi guys I am using react-select in my project along with Formik and Yup for validation The issue is even though I see an error in error object in the console after validating it through Yup but I am not able to show that error on the frontend

Here is the code below

```
export default function FormSection({
  onContinueButton,
  allFormValues,
  holders,
}) {
  console.log(holders, "hol12");

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      firstBirthDate: "",
      firstSmoker: "",
      secondBirthDate: "",
      secondSmoker: "",
    },

    onSubmit: (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
      console.log(formik.errors);
      console.log(formik.values, "valqwqrwe");

      setSubmitting(false);
      allFormValues(formik.values);
      console.log(values);
    },
    validationSchema: validationSchemaSectionTwo,
  });
  const options = [
    { value: "Não", label: "Não" },
    { value: "Sim", label: "Sim" },
  ];

  const handleChangeFirstHolder = (selectedOption) => {
    formik.setFieldValue("firstSmoker", selectedOption);
  };


  return (
    <div className="secondSection">
      <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        <React.Fragment>
 <p className="tab-text">Data Nascimento</p>
            <DatePicker
              selected={formik.values.firstBirthDate}
              onChange={date => {
                formik.setFieldValue('firstBirthDate', date)
              }}
              className="birth-date-calendar"
              dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
              name="firstBirthDate"
              placeholderText="DD-MM-AAAA"
              onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
            />
            {formik.errors.firstBirthDate && formik.touched.firstBirthDate && (
              <div className="formik-errors">{formik.errors.firstBirthDate}</div>
            )}


              <p className="tab-text">É fumador?</p>
              <Select
                value={formik.values.firstSmoker}
                name="firstSmoker"
                onChange={handleChangeFirstHolder}
                options={options}
                className="select-smoker"
                onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
              />
              {formik.errors.firstSmoker && formik.touched.firstSmoker && (
                <div className="formik-errors">{formik.errors.firstSmoker}</div>
              )}
            </React.Fragment>
    
            <br />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I also tried

```
onBlur={()=> {
       formik.setTouched({ firstSmoker: true });
   }}
```

but what this method does is as soon as i foucus
on `<Select/>` tag but then it sets `formik.touched.firstBirthDate` to undefined

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since you asked the question, but I believe is worth answering so others can also use it as a reference.

My solution would be to use the setFieldTouched method instead of the setTouched. From the [Formik documentation](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setfieldtouched-field-string-istouched-boolean-shouldvalidate-boolean--void), setFieldTouched sets the touched state **of a field** imperatively and is useful for creating custom input blur handlers. On the other hand, setTouched expects to set the value of the touched object completely.

Thus to use it in React Select:

```py
onBlur={() => { 
  formik.setFieldTouched("firstSmoker")
}}
```